# Lost WordPress website access after changing URL

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, site-url, home-url

I have changed the Site URL and Home URL of my website, after that I am not able to access it. The message appearing on the screen is "**this site can’t be reached**"

How do I get the access back?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cPanel and have an access of phpMyAdmin on your host, then find your DB, check the "siteurl" and "home" fields are correct in wp_options Table.

Or

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Or

If you have a cli access, then login into your Mysql, select a database and run below query

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace( option_value, 'http://oldsite.com/path', 'http://spankingnew.com/otherpath' )
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

(NOTE: make sure to change 'http://oldsite.com/path' with your correct URL and 'http://spankingnew.com/otherpath' with your edited URL in the query)

Comment: unfortunately i don't have any access on my phpMyAdmin or cli access

Comment: which web hosting are you using?

Comment: i used the free one (000webhost)